# Pourquoi c'est "Ajouter les dés de poivrons..." dans ma recette, et pas "Ajoutez les dés de poivrons..."?

Tags: infinitif, impératif

Je suis en train de lire une recette en français. Je me demande pourquoi l'infinitif est utilisé dans une expression comme "Ajouter les dés de poivrons..." à la place de l'impératif -> "Ajoutez les dés de poivrons...".

Est-ce que l'infinitif peut être utiliser comme une forme très polie de l'impératif?

Merci

Comment: Ah oui. Merci @livresque

Comment: C'est une bonne question ! Courage continue : )